# Evaluating a line integeral on the sides of a triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Let $C$ be the triangle with vertices $(0,0);(1,0);(0,1)$ , traversed in a counterclockwise direction ;

then what is the value of $\int_C(x+y)ds$ ? I'm having trouble with the range of parameter for each side of the triangle , Please help .

Comment: A generic parametrization of a line segment [A,B] is $(1-t)A+tB$, with $t=0..1$.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

In this version the counterclockwise nature of the traversal will be paid attention to.

The triangle has  $3$ sides. The parametric equations of the sides are

1. $x_1(t)=t,\,y_1(t)=0;\,\,0\le t \le 1;\,\,r_1(t)=\vec i t;\,\,|r'_1(t)|=1,$
   [image]
2. $x_2(t)=0,\ y_2(t)=1-t;\,\,0\le t \le 1;\,\,r_2(t)=\vec j (1-t);\,\,|r'_2(t)|=1,$
   [image]
3. $x_3(t)=1-t,\ y_3(t)=t;\,\,0\le t \le 1;\,\,r_3(t)=\vec i (1-t)+\vec jt;\,\,|r'_3(t)|=\left |-\vec i+\vec j\right |=\sqrt2.$
   [image]

---

The [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) has three parts then

$$\int_{\triangle}x+y\ ds=$$
$$\int_0^1 (x_1(t)+y_1(t))|r'_1(t)|\ dt+\int_0^1 (x_2(t)+y_2(t))|r'_2(t)|\ dt+\sqrt2\int_0^1 (x_3(t)+y_3(t))|r'_3(t)| \ dt=$$
$$=\int_0^1 t\ dt+\int_0^1 1-t\ dt+\sqrt2\int_0^1 1 \ dt=1+\sqrt2.$$

Comment: I did exactly that ; but the answer is supposed to come $-\sqrt 2$ ( it is a problem from Apostol's Calculus ; Volume II)

Comment: @SaunDev: I redid the calculation. I paid attention of the requirement that the traversal had to be counterclockwise. The result remained the same as the line integral has to be independent of the parametrization. Also, **the result cannot be negative because the function $(x+y)$ is positive** all over the line.